# Magic link for OP (original poster)

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

I just found out about magic links today and think they're awesome, but one additional type of magic link I would find really useful is the ability to reference the question author if commenting on a question, answering or commenting on an answer, or the answer author if commenting on an answer.

Maybe something like:

```
[opq] - question author
[opa] - answer author
```

Resulting in links like [3N1GM4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344265/3n1gm4).

Comment: What I'd like even more is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109878/autocomplete-username-references-in-answer-posts

Comment: Yes, I suppose that could possibly supersede what I'm describing, although I would find it handy to be able to tag the OP without having to scroll to check their username.

Comment: Why do you need this? The profile will be linked from the user card on the post anyway so I don't see any need for another link to it in the comments.

Comment: @MartinSmith because I often find myself referencing the OP (especially in comments) and it seems less rude to refer to them by name with a profile link than just to call them "the OP", which is quite impersonal. Just thinking about being nice to each other, which is a SE principle I believe?