# Auto-complete and link @usernames in answers

Tags: feature-request, autocomplete

It would be nice to have an easy way to link to user profiles from answers. It is common to give credit to helpful comments within answers.

Although it's possible to embed links to comments, that's not really useful because comments are meant to be ephemeral, and by making them part of the answer, they have fulfilled their purpose and could be deleted.

Simply mentioning the author of the comment, as in @HelpfulJoe, is not good enough, because if a reader wants to check out the profile of the user for more words of wisdom, he would have to search by name, which is tedious, error-prone, and may not even work, for example if the user has changed his display name in the meantime.

To make this really easy, it would be great to implement this with similar auto-completion as it works in comments. The auto-completion candidates should be limited to users who commented on the answer, and authors of other answers.

This feature-request is different from these similar previous questions:

- [Magic link for OP (original poster)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288787/magic-link-for-op-original-poster) -- that question is asking for magic links like `[opa]` and `[opq]` and with a more limited scope. I'm asking for auto-completion + linking by typing usernames prefixed with `@`, as it works in comments.
- [Autocomplete username references in answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109878/autocomplete-username-references-in-answer-posts) -- that question is asking for linking to other answers. That would be nice too, but I'm asking for linking to user profiles, as it works in comments.

My current workaround is to manually add the @username with a link to the profile. With minimal typing and mouse clicks:

1. Right-click on user link, copy URL
2. Click in the answer's text area where you want to insert the username reference, and press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to bring up the **Insert Hyperlink** pop-up
3. Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste the copied URL, and before closing the pop-up, press <kbd>Right</kbd> to jump to the end of the pasted URL, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> to select the last word, hopefully the entire username, if not then adjust the selection, press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to copy the username, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the pop-up
4. Type `@` and press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste the username

Comment: Only the title and first sentence of that post asks for the same, the rest is explaining something else. It's mainly asking to link to other answers from @username references, which is very different from what I'm asking here. I'm asking to link to the users themselves, and not only authors of other answers, but authors of comments as well. If the majority of that other question got implemented, that wouldn't be nearly good enough for what I'm asking here

Comment: oh, I see. sorry! They're pretty similar but I agree they're different now, retracted close vote! :)

Comment: Re: *“My current workaround is to manually add the @ username with a link to the profile. This is especially tedious when the @ username is long or not easy to type (fancy unicode names).”* Is there something about this workflow that prevents copying and pasting their username?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I can type your name but I cannot type easily ᔕᖺᘎᕊ's, so I have to copy paste such names. I copy paste slower than I type. Copy pasting just a link is annoying enough, if I have to copy paste a link *and* a username too, that's extremely annoying. The auto-completion feature would be really awesome.

Comment: @PythonMaster I explained in the question itself, and also in a comment responding to ᔕᖺᘎᕊ why this question is different from the other. Can you please explain why you disagree with my explanation and still think it's a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I can see that it would be faster. (Note though that the name is part of the link, so if one is already copying the profile's link, you get the name already copied with it, e.g.: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/ᔕᖺᘎᕊ`. That might be helpful to speed this up in the meantime when this feature doesn't exist.)

Comment: @PythonMaster great, then perhaps you can delete your "Possible duplicate" comment above (and retract any close votes)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I added my current complete workaround, with minimal typing and mouse clicks

Comment: **This isn't a duplicate** The marked dupe asks to link *to a post* whereas this one asks to link *to a user* (and users in comments).

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ true, but it is a dupe of other question. :)